# Display Authenticated User in HTML page

Tags: html, iis

I have a HTML page hosted on my internal network for some basic information. Its a static HTML page hosted on IIS as an Website. I have Windows Authentication enabled and Anonymous Authentication disabled. My default document is index.html. I am trying to display the authenticated user after logging in. I don't have a test as everything I have found mentions the use of PHP files or js scripts, but I only have the index.html file. Is this possible at all, or do I need to look at alternatives?

Comment: What is it you're trying to display once they've logged in, just a username?

Comment: Their full name from AD. First and Last name. I tried   <script type="text/javascript">
  var servername = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
  alert(servername);
  </script> but then just get a httpcontect not defined error.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily be able to do this with JS only unless you place the username using htmlinner and a span or something similar.

Comment: Do you have any examples on how I may be able to achieve this?

Comment: I'd need some code or screenshots in your question to visualise what you're tying to acheive